# how to change selected value color in select box in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to know how to change the selected value colori n select box in jQuery Mobile in iPad? Currently, it's ok in native Safari browser. When I render it in iPad Safari browser, it doesn't work.

Please check the following Image. I want to change different color to "Pink NRIC" when selected instead of white color.

[image]

Comment: If you don't tell people *what* it is you're trying to do, you're not going to get much help.  You haven't even said if you can't change it *via the UI, with your fingers* or you can't change it *programmatically*...

Comment: Color of what? Text? Back ground, Page, text field, theme, etc...............

Comment: @Phill... Just for text color

Comment: Now I can do it. http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2011/5/20/Change-jQueryMobile-Select-Box-active-style-color-in-iPad-safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know how to change the color of selected combo in jQueryMobile. Here is the solution.

The first part is I need to add new class name for active select box in stylesheet.

```
ui-select-active {color:#0000a0; text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #ffffff;}
```

After that, I need to declare above class name in jQueryMobile javascript file.

We need to add following coding after this **"activeBtnClass: "ui-btn-active","**

```
activeSelectClass: "ui-select-active",
```

Final part is we need to change existing coding in line 3491.

```
/* original coding */
button.addClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );

/* change to this one */
button.addClass( $.mobile.activeSelectClass );
```

[Change jQueryMobile Select Box active style color in iPad safari](http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2011/5/20/Change-jQueryMobile-Select-Box-active-style-color-in-iPad-safari)